# find regex in glob() search filesin directory php

Tags: php

I'm serching files in a directory

**PROBLEM**

I need to retrieve files whose directory matches with the word entered

I need something like:   `glob (gifs/[like $varSearched]/*.gif)`

**Directory**

```
 gifs/hello/1.gif
 gifs/hello/2.gif
 gifs/hello/3.gif

 gifs/claps/1.gif
 gifs/claps/2.gif

 gifs/wow/1.gif
 gifs/wow/2.gif
```

**PATH PHP** (it works but its needed to type all the file directory "hello", "wow", "claps" to retrieve the results). What I need is to type one or two letter only to retrieve the results

```
$dir="o"; // "o" is the searched term
$mdir = "../gifs/".$dir."/";
$files = glob($mdir.'*.gif');
foreach ($files as $gif){
$title = basename(dirname($gif));


$arr[] =  $title." - ".$gif;


}
$arr= implode("",$arr);
echo $arr;
```

**EXPECTED RESULTS**

```
 gifs/hello/1.gif
 gifs/hello/2.gif
 gifs/hello/3.gif
 gifs/wow/1.gif
 gifs/wow/2.gif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in case with file name, you can add `*` as a placeholder for any symbol in directory name:

```
$mdir = "../gifs/*".$dir."*/";    // see `*` here?
$files = glob($mdir.'*.gif');
// rest of the code here
```

Comment: wow, I'm so grateful, I was twisting my mind with long regexs, `*` is the solution, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this.

```
<?php

$search = "c";

$dir = "gifs/";

$folder = exec( "ls -d ".$dir.$search."*" );

$files = glob($folder.'/*.gif');

foreach ( $files as $gif ) {



    $title = basename( dirname( $gif ) );

    $arr[] =  $title." - ".$gif;


}

print_r( $arr );

$arr = implode( "", $arr );

//echo $arr."\n";
```

Replacing the `$search = "c";` with whatever directory letter you want and replacing `$dir = "gifs/";` with whatever your filepath is.

**Print_r with search letter "c"**

```
Array
(
    [0] => claps - gifs/claps/1.gif
    [1] => claps - gifs/claps/2.gif
)
```

**Print_r with search letter "h"**

```
Array
(
    [0] => hello - gifs/hello/1.gif
    [1] => hello - gifs/hello/2.gif
    [2] => hello - gifs/hello/3.gif
)
```

You could also wrap this in a function and pass it the two arguments `$search` and `$dir` and add a `return $arr` at the end.